# Office 365 Unified API preview: beta/me/calendar/events InternalErrorServer

Tags: office365api, office365-restapi

This was working up until yesterday (11/03/2015), but now, whenever I try to GET **/beta/me/calendar/events** (e.g., through https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net), I get an `InternalServerError`:

```
Error: 500 - Internal Server Error
 See Response Headers for details.
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/REDACTED/$metadata#users('REDACTED')/Calendar/Events","value":[{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "8bf14cc8-8a2d-4f7e-a86f-0b11df3efe96",
      "date": "2015-11-03T16:39:18"
    }
  }
}
```

Has the preview beta calendar event endpoint changed?

Answer (score 0):

We investigated and this is a deployment issue. Your account has not been migrated to the right build. Users from a single organization are distributed across multiple servers, and these servers are upgraded at different times.  I know, this makes it difficult right now, but things should be stable in a few days. Worldwide deployment of that build is at 80%  right now.
Remember Office 365 unified API is currently in preview, we are working hard to release it soon, as part of this we will continue making some changes, including breaking changes, in /beta to incorporate feedback and improve the API as we get ready for v1.0.  Once v1.0 launches, we will continue to update beta on a regular basis, even with potentially breaking changes, but versioned end points will not have breaking changes once they're released.